# AWS Lambda adding two number in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to know how to read multiple inputs and perform operation on those inputs.
I want to my aws lambda function to read two input integers and add those integers and return the sum.

I am new to aws lambda.

My code:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class AWSCalculator implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream,
                              final Context context) throws IOException {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("Loading Java Lambda handler of ProxyWithStream");

        DataObject data = mapper.readValue(inputStream, DataObject.class);
        data.calculateResults(context);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
        logger.log(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DataObject {
    @JsonProperty("Number1")
    int number1;
    @JsonProperty("Number2")
    int number2;
    int sum;
    int product;
    int difference;
    float quotient;

    public void calculateResults(Context context) {

        LambdaLogger log = context.getLogger();


        sum = number1 + number2;
        product = number1 * number2;
        difference = Math.abs(number1 - number2);
        quotient = (float) number1 / (float) number2;

        Logger.getLogger("The Sum is : " + String.valueOf(sum));   


    }
}
```

how to read inputs from lambda function?

Comment: What part is not working?  It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: This DataObject Class is not working. I dont know how to get print the result in logs. I tried executing on aws console, but not getting the sum of the numbers in logs. Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have just a minor issue.  In your `DataObject` class you're not logging correctly.  You pass in the `Context` to get the `LambdaLogger` but then use `Logger` from the `java.util.logging` package.  Change the code:

```
Logger.getLogger("The Sum is : " + String.valueOf(sum));
```

to be

```
log.log("The Sum is : " + sum);
```

By using the `LambdaLogger` your output goes to CloudWatch easier.  I also removed the `String.valueOf` as it isn't needed.

Once you do that your code is working fine.  I ran it through the AWS console with an input like:

```
{
  "Number1": 5,
  "Number2": 3
}
```

and in the CloudWatch logs I got:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir...!! i can see where i made the mistake. Its working now